# preg_split() help, properly formatted regular expression

Tags: php, split, expression, explode

I'm pretty weak in regular expressions.

I want to split on these characters:

- plus "+"
- space " "
- hyphen "-"
- underscore "_"

This is what I have:

```
preg_split('/\+|-|\s|_/', $string ),
```

...I suspect this is not right - on the "+" sign. I'd love some advice.

Answer (score 4):

`preg_split('/[+\s_-]/', $string);` should work for you.  This is creating a character class using your characters as opposed to a series of pipes.

**Note** - it is sometimes important that the `-` be last in the character class, so I tend to always put it there to be safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saves the day.